# Matlab: does parfor transparency requirement implies no non-vector variables can be used?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am now struggling with Matlab parfor transparency requirement. As far as my understanding goes, transparency requirement doesn't allow any variable to be used because many workers will be reading/writing to the same variable over and over. There is no mutex or anything that prevents this from happening, as I searched around.

In terms of code, here is a simple example:

```
a = 0;
realDataIneed = [];
parfor i = 1:10
    a = a+i
    realDataIneed = [realDataIneed a];
end
```

In this case, if parfor is for, then realDataIneed will just be `[1 3 6 ...]`, a nice predictable sequence. In multiprocessing paradigm, will each worker overlap and access the same variable unpredictably?

(It seems to me that having an array that each worker access its variable designated by array index is more reasonable, because no conflict will happen, although reading and writing to the same array could also be problematic.)

Can someone elaborate on this matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a *transparency* problem (those are about whether `parfor` can see from the text of the program which variables are used inside the loop); rather, this is a variable classification problem. `parfor` supports two types of outputs from the loop:

1. *sliced* outputs which are indexed by the loop variable
2. *reduction* outputs which are formed using a recognised reduction

In your case, `a` taken on its own would be a reduction output because it's updated in the correct form. Concatenation is also a valid form of reduction - but unfortunately, the combination of summation and concatenation isn't a valid reduction. Basically, what you're trying to achieve here is MATLAB's `cumsum`, and that isn't associative (which is the requirement for a `parfor` reduction).

What I'd do in this case is simply emit the vector of values and then perform the `cumsum` back at the MATLAB client. E.g.

```
parfor i = 1:10
    a(i) = i;
end
realDataIneed = cumsum(a);
```

Comment: In short, does each parfor worker gets its own version of variable "a" and work on it individually? Or there will be race condition about read/write to the same "a" among all workers? The example I gave isn't what I really want to do, it's just to illustrate my intention to work with a shared variable among workers.

Comment: In a `parfor` reduction variable, each worker reduces locally, and then sends the locally reduced result back to the client for more reduction. Each worker gets a block of a sliced variable which it sends back to the client. Because of the restricted nature of `parfor`, it is not possible to express a race condition.

Comment: I should add: it is not possible to express a race condition using only MATLAB variables. You can certainly shoot yourself in the foot using the filesystem or whatever.